# Get the Debian version of the sources of a Python package

Tags: debian, python, packaging

What is the most easy/intuitive way to get code for some Python package that is distributed with Debian if I am not on Debian (no `apt-get` here)?

For example, there was a bug with `pip` on Debian and I want to see if it is fixed by comparing its code with upstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go to `https://packages.debian.org/source/<release>/<package>` where `<release>` is the particular release of Debian I was interested in, and `<package>` is the package name.

For example:  https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/python-pip

From there, I would scroll down to the bottom of the page and download the compressed `tar` archives (original source, and Debian's additions to this source).

If I didn't know the name of the package, only that it should contain the executable `pip`, I would go to https://packages.debian.org/ and search for "packages that contain files named like this" and enter `bin/pip` in the search box at the bottom of the page.

It is also possible to use an URL on the following format to get to the search results directly:

https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin/pip

Comment: @StephenKitt, so Debian distributes upstream source in unmodified form in source tarball?

Comment: Yes, the `.orig` tarball is usually the unmodified upstream source. (When it is modified, it's generally-speaking to remove non-distributable portions of the source; such modifications are indicated using a `+dfsg`, `+ds` or `+repack` suffix.)